# How to display line by line a csv file in PHP with a particular structure?

Tags: php, fopen, implode, fgetcsv

I have this code that reads a csv file and displays it in this form :

```
REFERENCE;COLOR;QUANTITY;TURNOVER;SELL TROUGH;COMMENT 
GJK0C9;8952;3;90;3%;Pack S   
GJKCS4;399;2;19;10%;Windows    
GSIJS5;9224;18;128;12%;New co   
BBBOF1;90;17;116;13%;In sales    
...
```

First the header and then all the lines.

I would like to display like this:

```
REFERENCE : GJK0C9    
COLOR: 8952    
QUANTITY: 3    
TURNOVER : 90    
SELL TROUGH: 3%   
HOW: Pack S  

REFERENCE : GJKCS4    
COLOR: 399    
....
```

And so on.

How to display the result with this format?

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    echo '<table>';

    // Get headers
    if (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo '<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $data).'</th></tr>';
    }

    // Get the rest
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $data).'</td></tr>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo '</table>';
}


?>
```

Comment: Any attempts to change provided code?

Comment: I think the OP hopes that one of us is going to do ALL THAT for them @u_mulder

Comment: No I managed to display the lines in a row with the title separated but I can't separate the columns in my csv file to display them.

Comment: Yes we can see, but that does not do what you want it to, so you will have to amend the code quite considerably to get the output you require

Comment: Columns are under comment `// Get headers`. Do not overwrite `$data` and you will have your columns.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'll try to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code will work with a bit modification:

1.Get headers first and assigne them to an array

2.Now loop over the values and combine them to header array to make them key value pair array

3.Loop over this key-value pair array and print it in desired format

4.Your delimiter is `;` not `,` (according to what you shown in code sample)

```
<?php
$column = []; //create an array
if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{

    // Get headers
    if (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
    {
        $column = $data; // assign header value to array
    }

    // Get the rest
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
    {
        $row = array_combine($column,$data); // combine header with values
        foreach($row as $key=>$value){
            echo $key." : ".$value; //print key value pair to get desired output
            echo PHP_EOL;//you can use '<br>' as well
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```